# How to generate a pandas dataframe with multiple columns from list

Tags: python, list, pandas

This should be simple, but I'm having a tough time with it.  Basically, I have 4 strings that I'm generating for each iteration of my for loop and then adding them to a list.  I want every 4 items to be a row and I need to be able to give the 4 columns header values.  This looks like a job for pandas, but I just can't get it the way I need it.  Thank you in advance for your guidance.  Here is what I have so far:

```
def main():

    credentials = get_credentials()
    http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
    service = discovery.build('calendar', 'v3', http=http)
    deadline_list = []
    pattern1 = re.compile(r'(?::)(.+$)')
    pattern2 = re.compile(r'(?:.+:\s+)(\w+\s+\w+)')

    StartDate = '2017-05-14'
    EndDate = '2017-05-19'

    print('\nGetting events within date range\n')
    eventsResult = service.events().list(
        calendarId='primary', timeMin=StartDate+'T00:00:01.000Z', timeMax=EndDate+'T23:59:59.000Z', 
        singleEvents=True,
        orderBy='startTime').execute()
    events = eventsResult.get('items', [])

    if not events:
        print('No upcoming events found.')

    for event in events:
        if re.search('^\d+',event['location']):

            start = event['start'].get('dateTime', event['start'].get('date'))
            deadline_type = pattern1.search(event['description']).group(1).rstrip('\r')
            client_name = pattern2.match(event['description']).group(1)
            location = ' '.join(event['location'].split())
            deadline_list.extend([location, start, deadline_type, client_name])

        else:
            pass

    print(deadline_list)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are passing `deadline_list` to pandas, you want to use:

```
deadline_list.append([location, start, deadline_type, client_name])
```

instead of `.extend`. 
This will create a list of lists, which pandas will accept when creating a data frame via

```
df = pd.DataFrame(deadline_list, columns=['location','start','deadline_type','client_name'])
```

Also, you don't need `else: pass`, if the condition in the `if` statement is not `True`, nothing will happen anyway.